# SLF4J put and immediate get is failing

Tags: java, slf4j

I've written a little wrapper for SLF4J MDC.

```
import org.slf4j.MDC;

import java.util.UUID;


public final class MdcWrapperUtility {



    public static final String MDC_TRANSACTION_ID_KEY_NAME = "MDC_TRANSACTION_ID";

    private MdcWrapperUtility() {
    }

    public static String getId() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        String returnValue = MDC.get(MDC_TRANSACTION_ID_KEY_NAME);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static String setId() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String setAndReturnValue = threadName + uuid;
        MDC.put(MDC_TRANSACTION_ID_KEY_NAME, setAndReturnValue);

        String sanityCheck = MDC.get(MDC_TRANSACTION_ID_KEY_NAME);
        if (null == sanityCheck || sanityCheck.length() <= 0)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("MDC did not persist. How is this even happening?????");
        }

        return setAndReturnValue;
    }
}
```

At first, after I called "setId()"...i would later call "getId" and it would be null.
You can see that I DID verify the thread names...understanding "the thread" is the "magic" that allows MDC to work.

So then I did an MDC.get IMMEDIATELY after the MDC.put, and it is coming back as null.

???

Gaaa.

In my proof of concept project I have:

```
implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: slf4jVersion
implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: slf4jSimpleVersion
```

Exact versions below:

```
    slf4jSimpleVersion = '1.7.30'
    slf4jVersion = '1.7.30'
```

Both proof-of-concept and "real" give me a null MDC.get (aka, I get the "MDC did not persist. How is this even happening?????" exception.

The only other clue I can offer is that I do NOT have a monolith.
I have a multi module gradle project.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

I am using variables (defined in my root build.gradle) for my versions, so I do not have a mismatch version in any module(s).

APPEND ONE:

Ok, so I know why it is returning "null".
It is using the concrete

```
public class NOPMDCAdapter implements MDCAdapter {

    public void clear() {
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return null;
    }

    public void put(String key, String val) {
    }

    public void remove(String key) {
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCopyOfContextMap() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setContextMap(Map<String, String> contextMap) {
        // NOP
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out.

And of course, hindsight is 20/20.

I should have focused more on the "simple" part of "'slf4j-simple'"

That does NOT (really) support MDC, and it goes to the NOPMDCAdapter. (I think NOP-MDC-Adapter means "no operation mdc adapter")

When I add a "real" concrete for SLF4J (like logback), I get "real" MDC functionality.

So remove the "simple" and add a "real" one (like logback)

```
implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: logbackClassicVersion
implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: slf4jVersion


    logbackClassicVersion = '1.2.3'
```

And now I get an MDC with my "get".

The "concrete" MDCAdapter after I add 'logback-classic' reference becomes the below one, which actually works.

```
public class LogbackMDCAdapter implements MDCAdapter {
}
```

Important documentation nuggets:

(from http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html )

> Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) support "Mapped Diagnostic Context" is
> essentially a map maintained by the logging framework where the
> application code provides key-value pairs which can then be inserted
> by the logging framework in log messages. MDC data can also be highly
> helpful in filtering messages or triggering certain actions.
>
> SLF4J supports MDC, or mapped diagnostic context. **If the underlying
> logging framework offers MDC functionality, then SLF4J will delegate
> to the underlying framework's MDC. Note that at this time, only log4j
> and logback offer MDC functionality.** If the underlying framework
> does not offer MDC, for example java.util.logging, then SLF4J will
> still store MDC data but the information therein will need to be
> retrieved by custom user code.
>
> Thus, as a SLF4J user, you can take advantage of MDC information in
> the presence of log4j or logback, but without forcing these logging
> frameworks upon your users as dependencies.